# The slope of a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, spatial, lme4-nlme

I want to know whether `x2` is better than `x1` in explaining `y`. My data frame looks like:

```
study  y     x1     x2    Latitude    Longitude
1      1.2   0.5    0.7   -4389124    12118426
1      1.8   1.2    1.5   -4389926    12110034
2      1.6   1.2    1.3   -4392865    12104837
```

I used

```
glmmPQL(y ~ x1 + x2, random=~1|Study, data=Data,
        correlation=corExp(form=~Latitude+Longitude), family=gaussian)

glmmPQL(y ~ x1, random=~1|Study, data=Data, 
        correlation=corExp(form=~Latitude+Longitude), family=gaussian) 

glmmPQL(y ~ x2, random=~1|Study, data=Data,
        correlation=corExp(form=~Latitude+Longitude), family=gaussian)
```

How do I know which model is best?

I was told first use the mixed model framework, then use AIC to rank all models, and then correct the precision of slope estimates using unconditional confidence intervals. What does this mean?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear as to what you are asking. There seems to be two questions here: (a) how to know if `x1` or `x2` is better at predicting `y`. This could be done in a number of ways. But you also are asking (b) how to compare non-nested models. Are you asking which model tests your hypothesis best? Or which combinations test your hypothesis best?

Comment: @MarkWhite My goal is know if x1 or x2 is better at predicting y. Since I have spatial data in different studies. I googled and selected `glmmPQL()`. But I don't know how to interpret the outcomes. So I couldn't tell which model is the best.

Comment: @MarkWhite . I also use `m_study1_x1 = gls(y ~ x1, data=study1, correlation=corExp(form=~Lat+Long))` and `m_study1_x2 = gls(y ~ x2, data=study1, correlation=corExp(form=~Lat+Long))` in each study. But a reviewer said this would inflate Type I. I was told first use the mixed model framework, then use AIC to rank all models, and then correct the precision of slope estimates using unconditional confidence intervals. I don't know what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @Rebecca did you ever get to the bottom of this?